# Is there any Blogger (blogspot) not mobile conditional format

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I would like to load javascript files only on Desktop version of my Google blogspot (blogger.com) since I need a light version of my blog for mobile.

I came through followings, but not working

```
<b:if cond != 'data:blog.isMobile'>;
<b:if cond = !'data:blog.isMobile'>;
<b:if cond = '!data:blog.isMobile'>;
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType !== "data:blog.isMobile">
```

How can I write "is Not Mobile" conditional in Google blogspot? Thanks in advance for all answers.

================================================================================

Update: I'm using following code at the moment and it's working but better ideas are welcome

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile'>

<b:else/>
    //I include javascript files here and they only appear on desktop version
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `true` or `false` statements in blogger conditional tags in this case.
This is the best way ;)

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile == &quot;false&quot;'>
//Contents inside this, will only appear in Desktop version.
</b:if>
```

***Edit #1:***

This will work only if you have enabled mobile template, and set it to custom.

[image]

[image]

And it does work on Chrome's mobile emulator. (will be redirected to mobile version if visiting from a mobile device or with an emulator that reflects a mobile Browser User Agent. it will add `?m=1` at the end of the URL)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: A few questions here:
1. Is this still working if Blogger mobile template is disabled?
2. Does it work on Chrome's mobile emulator?
Thanks!

Comment: @MuhammedAslamC : Cool, no wonder my `isMobile` condition doesn't work because setting it to custom mobile screwed up my design either. I disabled them altogether and use the ordinary way to make my desktop version responsive: `viewport` meta tag outside the `isMobile` condition plus `@media` query CSS.

Answer (score 5):

i've found a useful conditional tag to display only on mobile view recently. this conditional tag worked even i didn't activate mobile template.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest == &quot;true&quot;'>
<!-- showed only if browser request as a mobile -->
<b:else/>
<!-- showed if browser not requesting as a mobile device-->
</b:if>
```

Try use this with my example:
in this example, thumbnail image removed when mobile request value is true and displaying thumbnail if not requested.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest == &quot;true&quot;'>
            <div>
              <div class='item-title'><a expr:href='data:post.href' expr:title='data:post.snippet'><data:post.title/></a></div>
            </div>
<b:else/>
            <div class='item-thumbnail-only'>
              <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnail'>
                <div class='item-thumbnail'>
                  <a expr:href='data:post.href' expr:title='data:post.snippet' target='_blank'>
                    <img border='0' expr:alt='data:post.title' expr:height='data:thumbnailSize' expr:src='data:post.thumbnail' expr:width='data:thumbnailSize'/>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </b:if>
              <div class='item-title'><a expr:href='data:post.href' expr:title='data:post.snippet'><data:post.title/></a></div>
            </div>
</b:if>
```

you can find this conditional tag value in view-source of your blogspot page.

*data:blog.isMobileRequest* is a condition wich listening value of **m=** query on address bar.

web address followed with **m=1** it mean *isMobileRequest: true;*

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmWRK.png)

and if not followed with **m=1** or followed with **m=0** it mean *isMobileRequest: false;*

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRQCn.png)

Answer (score 1):

Blogger's own mobile data tag is enough i guess. but if still you are looking for alternate way, you can use some JS logic. I suppose you already knew that blogger redirects all mobile devices to `http://yourdomain.blogspot.com/?m=1`
Where the `?m=1` part enables the mobile version.

Now you can use that redirect to your favor.

Create a Javascript checkpoint which checks that if **Request.QueryString** has `?m=1` if it has then do nothing else load your's Javascript which you want.

--Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help but since I need a lighter version my blog, I can't use JS conditional statement because js can only execute after it is rendered to visitor's browser. Whereas, blogger conditional tag execute on blogger server and then render to visitor's browser.

Comment: You wanted an alternate way, which i have answered above. I will recommend you to use the Blogger Conditional tags aswell. :)

Answer (score 1):

So far this is the best and **updated conditional tag** I've found. and **it works fine weather the mobile template activated or not.**

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest == &quot;false&quot;'>
<!-- display 'something' if browser not requesting as a mobile device-->
<p>Something!</p>
</b:if>
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is the best answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use blogger's mobile platform along with media queries like this

```
<link expr:href='data:blog.url + &quot;?m=1&quot;' media='only screen and (max-width: 640px)' rel='alternate'/>
```

which will simply display the mobile version for your chosen media screen. similarly you can attach your js or css files using this method to display your stuff on mobile platforms.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding your extra HTML/Javascript as widget, there is another handy way to do this by setting the value of `mobile` attribution in widget elements.

To prevent your widget loading on mobile,

`<b:widget id='Attribution1' mobile='no' title='Attribution' type='Attribution'>`

Or to make it only available in mobile.

`<b:widget id='Attribution1' mobile='only' title='Attribution' type='Attribution'>`

For more details, you can see it [here](http://code.blogger.com/2011/11/introducing-custom-mobile-templates.html)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the term `isMobile` is too broad and may not be able to enable you to deliver expected result for all screen sizes -- this could be the limitation of Blogger in handling mobile responsiveness at the moment. To make your javascript conditionally work like CSS `@media` query, use this example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 950px)').matches) {
             // Do something for screen sizes not wider than 950px.
        }
        else { 
             // Do something for screen sizes wider than 950px,
             // which is pretty much what you're looking for,
             // that is (Not isMobile) equivalent.
        }

</script>
```

For my case, I disabled Blogger mobile template entirely and apply the following approach:

1. Put the existing `viewport` meta tag outside the `isMobile` condition.
2. Use CSS `@media` query to detect various screen sizes.
3. Use the above javascript for various screen sizes.

But of course, you can still apply the approach listed above by enabling custom mobile template (with **Custom** option selected) provided it doesn't screw up much of your existing customized design when clicking on the **Preview** button.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the old CSS method that's my case.

1. Put `meta` tag after`<head>`:

Than:

HTML

```
<div class="mobile">
  Mobile Content
</div>
<div class='desktop'>
  Desktop Content
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* if you are using desktop first*/
.mobile{
  display:none;
}
@media (max-width: 960px){
  .desktop{
    display:none;
  }
  .mobile{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

[HTML and CSS codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5KJr.jpg)